# Sort rows by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

A the title says, I'm looking for a way to sort a set of rows from a MySQL table.

I've simplified my example a bit, but the resulting solution should apply to my exact setup as well.Here's my setup:

```
events
----------
event_name
created
updated


Event A 
12-09-2012
14-09-2012

Event B
12-09-2012
-

Event C
09-09-2012
13-09-2012
```

I'm looking for a way to sort the rows based on most recent 'activity', so whichever date is the newest. So with the above values, the result should be A, C, B. (from most recent to older). It is worth noting that I can't change anything about the tables.

How would I go around doing this?

Regards,
Wouter

Comment: [Show us what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why bot sort it in your program?

Comment: @njk: That's just the thing, I don't know enough MySQL to know where to start and everything that's come up in searches was about sorting by multiple columns in succession (i.e. first one, then the other) and not simultaniously.

A thing I thought off, but not know if it is even possible, is to selected the highest value of the 2 columns as an alias and order by that. But I'm not sure how to compare date fields...

Comment: @James Black: I'm trying to do this in MySQL first for performance reasons. If it turns out that it isn't possible with MySQL or it is extremely slow I'll turn to PHP to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might be on to something here...

```
SELECT *, GREATEST(created, updated) AS last_activity FROM events ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

This does seem to work, but I'll have to do some testing to see if it is foolproof.

Comment: +1 - This is the first time I upvoted someone answering his own question, but, this approach is one I would never have thought of.

Comment: @James Black: There's something about trying to explain to someone what you are looking for that really makes you really think about it. Happens to me a lot...

But at least this will help people looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should be this simple

```
 SELECT event_Name From Events
 ORDER created DESC
```

Comment: That would just sort it by the 'created' column which would result in this order: A, B, C. Not exactly what I am looking for...